# Search for the most populated area in a game of life matrix

Tags: c, search, conways-game-of-life

I programmed a game of life in C and it works quiet well, the only problem the game board is much bigger than can be displayed. I know the number of rows and and the columns the that the monitor can display and I thought it would be a great idea following the action so to say (searching for the most populated area). Therefor I wrote a little function to receive the 4 indexes of the corners of the part of the  field I should display, but somehow the code seems to give random sections, which sometimes are obliviously false, the calculated worth of the living cells (max) is completely false (sometimes even bigger than the whole matrix it self). Here is the code:

```
int* most_populated_area(int m, int n, bool a[m][n], int r, int c){
    int * rr=malloc(sizeof(int)*4); //return value
    rr[0]=0;
    rr[1]=r;
    rr[2]=0;
    rr[3]=c; //we first assume that the most populated arrea is upper left corner
    int summe=0;
    int max=0; //to controll wheater or not we found a more populated area we need a summe and the max we founded until now
    for(int isearch=0; isearch<m; isearch++){ //we search the matrix row for row
        for(int jsearch=0; jsearch<n; jsearch++){ // and column for column
            for(int ik=0; ik<=r; ik++){ // now from the current flied we go as many rows we are allowed
                for(int jl=0; jl<=c; jl++){ //and also as many columns we are allowed to go
                    int iks=isearch+ik; //we looking on the field is 0 to r
                    int jls=jsearch+jl; //and 0 to c flieds away from our current field
                    if(iks>=m){ //if the field is outside the matrix we have to go back  
                        iks%=r; // iks is clearly bigger than r (because m bigger than r) but iks%r can be r-1 at most,
                        //so we have the rest from iks through r over the edge 
                    }
                    if(jls>=n){ //analog to iks
                        jls%=c;
                    }
                    summe+=a[iks][jls];
                }
            }
            if(summe>max){// the summe is greater than the max we found a more populated area and we save the the results
                max=summe;
                rr[0]=isearch;
                rr[1]=(isearch+r>=m)?(isearch+r)%r:isearch+r;
                rr[2]=jsearch;
                rr[3]=(jsearch+c>=n)?(jsearch+c)%c:jsearch+c;
            }
            summe=0; //anyway we reset the summe to search accurate
        }
    }
    printf("Lifing in this area %d \n", max);
    return rr;
}
```

Comment: Too many nested `for` loops, are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: Also, the most populated area of what size?

Comment: Size appears to be `r` by `c`

Comment: Could be simplified somewhat by doing: `for (int isearch = 0; isearch < (m - r); isearch++)` and the corresponding change on the other axis.  This might even solve your problem as these: `if (iks >= m) { iks %= r; }` don't seem right to me.

Comment: If your displaying a rectangular area you can just go through and try every possible area. Thus making it take `O((n-n1)*(m-m1)*n1*m1)` time where your board is `n x m` and the rectangle `n1 x m1` in size. This may be suitable for your board/rectangle size.

Comment: My monitor displays 1920 x1080 pixels. Are you using a text console of say 80x25 characters?

Comment: I would say that I need 4 loops so that I thoroughly search, my idea was making every flied the upper left corner of field to display and see how much is populated in these field.

Comment: @Vane Yes I use a console to display this, also the window isn't always full with.

Comment: @Murphy that was my idea as well, I get every area with every field being the upper left corner, there for I use my 4 loops.

Comment: I can't solve your problem except to say: move the mountain and aim for a GUI presentation: 1 pixel per life.

Comment: @Hascall How would your method would found more populated in the right half of the matrix? Yeah I also suspect the mistake to be somewhere there, but the field can suspend the edges of the matrix and come in at line/coloumn 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approximate solution that is O(n).

Split the board into x and y components and search for the most populous X and Y values. Then set those as the midpoints (adjusted for the edges) to be displayed.